# Webdriver.io - visual regression Service compare not recognized with multi remote

Tags: webdriver-io

I got visual regression working in webdriver.io and it is very wonderful.  I would, however, like to also use it with multi remote.  When I add the necessary configuration to my wdio.conf.js file for multiremote, I get the following error

```
Error: Please provide a visualRegression configuration with a compare method in your wdio-conf.js!
```

when running my tests and the regression service no longer works.

My relevent wdio.conf.js settings are configured as such:

```
//...
capabilities: {
    browserA: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    },
    browserB: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    }
},
// ...
services: ['visual-regression'],

visualRegression: {
  compare: new VisualRegressionCompare.LocalCompare({
  referenceName: getScreenshotName(path.join(process.cwd(), 'screenshots/reference')),
  screenshotName: getScreenshotName(path.join(process.cwd(), 'screenshots/taken')),
  diffName: getScreenshotName(path.join(process.cwd(), 'screenshots/diff')),
  }),
  viewportChangePause: 500,
  widths: [1280, 1600],
  orientations: ['landscape', 'portrait'],
},
```

Any help would be much appreciated!